# Download 5 images from urls

Tags: java, android, json, android-image

Im trying to download 5 images from the response of a JSON, i have managed to get the URLs of the images and am able to download the image if i hard code one of the image locations into the code.

How would i do it so that i can download all 5 images.

Below is the request code:

```
public void getImage(String url, final ImageView imageView) {
    ImageRequest requestImage = new ImageRequest(url, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
            System.out.println("Image Url is: " + response);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(response);
            System.out.println();

        }
    }, 0, 0, null, null);
    queue.add(requestImage);
}
```

Below is the code that passes the image Url from the response and sets the image in the xml based on the ID

FYI: bp_promo1 is the hard coded image added into the request

```
try {

            System.out.println("Size of PromoItemsArray is: " + home.promoItemsArray.size());


            for (int i = 0; i < home.promoItemsArray.size(); i++) {
                String imageUrl = home.promoItemsArray.get(i).imageUrl;

                request.getImage(imageUrl, bp_promo1);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error is: " + e + " - Exception is it: " + e.getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber());
        }
}
```

My idea was to add all five images to an array then pass each item in the array to the network call?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way I managed to fix the issue was below?

```
public void getImage(String url, final Object object) {
    ImageLoader.ImageCache imageCache = new BitmapLruCache();
    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(queue, imageCache);
    imageLoader.get(url, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {


            Bitmap responseBitmap = response.getBitmap();
            ImageView imageView;
            ImageButton imageButton;
            HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView;

            if (object instanceof ImageView) {

                imageView = (ImageView) object;
                imageView.setImageBitmap(responseBitmap);

            } else if (object instanceof ImageButton) {

                imageButton = (ImageButton) object;
                imageButton.setImageBitmap(responseBitmap);

            } else if (object instanceof HorizontalScrollView) {

                horizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) object;
                horizontalScrollView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), responseBitmap));

            }
        }
```

I just passed through a Object and manipulated the code based on the source of the Object type